How to create a type of an object that will pick its keys by itself?
I'm using TypeScript and I'm creating form schemas for my forms in my app. So for consistency I want to create a type that my forms will follow.
So below are the types that I have created:
type TOptions = { title: string; key: string };

type TFormSchema = Record<string, TOptions>;


and here is one of my form schemas:
export const ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA = {
  GUESTS: { title: 'Guests', key: 'guests' },
  CHECK_IN: { title: 'Check In', key: 'check-in' },
  CHECK_OUT: { title: 'Check Out', key: 'check-out' },
  FIRST_NAME: { title: 'First Name', key: 'firstName' },
  LAST_NAME: { title: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName' },
  EMAIL: { title: 'Email', key: 'email' },
  MOBILE: { title: 'Mobile', key: 'mobileNo' },
  REQUEST: { title: 'Request', key: 'request' },
};

Now the issue that I'm facing is as long as I'm not giving ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA a type I'm able to access its properties in any way i.e. either by dot notation or by destructuring I get VS Code suggestions.
But as soon as I give the type to my ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA as ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA: TFormSchema I get nothing, no suggestions at all.
Is there any way to get it over with?
I have tried defining the type as:
type TFormSchema<K> = {[P in keyof K]: TOptions};

but I get this error:

is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

and many other things.

If you do not give a type to the object, then its type is inferred from the keys it has and hence you are able to access it. If you give a type Record<string, TOptions>, this is too wide, since you basically say any string can be the key. You either can use as const (const assertion) or can define a proper type by defining all keys inside the type too

hmm yeah sounds reasonable, so I guess it would be a better approach to first define the form keys type and then use the generic TFormSchema type with those keys type, right!?

Hi @TusharShahi after many days of research and tweaking. finally, I found out that my salvation was in using const assertion.
I'll be posting my answer about what I did and what issues I overcame to finally maintain reusability and consistency across all of my forms, form, and validation schemas.
Thanks for the guidance tough!

Since my previous example didn't work, using a class and then calling the class' static fields would work and include less code and it would solve your problem.
type TOptions = { title: string; key: string };

class RoomBookingFormSchema {
  public static readonly GUESTS: TOptions = { title: 'Guests', key: 'guests' };
  public static readonly CHECK_IN: TOptions = { title: 'Check In', key: 'check-in' };
  public static readonly CHECK_OUT: TOptions = { title: 'Check Out', key: 'check-out' };
  public static readonly FIRST_NAME: TOptions = { title: 'First Name', key: 'firstName' };
  public static readonly LAST_NAME: TOptions = { title: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName' };
  public static readonly EMAIL: TOptions = { title: 'Email', key: 'email' };
  public static readonly MOBILE: TOptions = { title: 'Mobile', key: 'mobileNo' };
  public static readonly REQUEST: TOptions = { title: 'Request', key: 'request' };
}

RoomBookingFormSchema.GUESTS.key; // 'guests'

Let me know if this worked better :)

that's the exact thing that I want to avoid, I don't want to create separate types for each of my forms in my app and then send them to the type. I might be wrong, but that seems too exhausting to me! To create the keys type first and then the form and so on and so forth!!!

@TamurTaj I changed the code and now it uses a class instead and you get the fields suggested, which is what you wanted at the beginning right?

thanks for your responses it was indeed another good approach to go with but I opted to create types for the schemas and kept my peace with it. I'll be sharing my answer soon

Thanks to @TusharShahi and @Raphael Canciani for their comments and guidance!
So here is what I ended up doing.
As per the question you can see, I had a type for my form but as mentioned that type was too wide for typescript to guess anything right!
I tried defining the union type for the generic form schema but that was only solving the 25% of the issue I was facing.
For the sake of reference, I was trying to achieve a single source of truth for my forms, forms schemas, and Zod validation schema, As I was working with NextJs, Shadcn UI, Zod, and react-hook-form.
So if I fix one thing the other breaks, i.e.
the type wasn't helping me with the suggestion at the time of usage,

it wasn't giving a proper type reference (i.e. as TOptions it only
shows the type for string, not the actual value that I had),
it wasn't helping me in defining the Zod validation schemas as Zod was
not able to differentiate between the keys of the object and create a
union type which in turn creates problems when I use that schema with
my form components (i.e. results in value types mix up as union),

So the solution to all of my problems was a simple const assertion.
So instead of doing:
/*
Let's assume you have created a union type for the keys e.g: 

TRoomBookingFormKeys
*/

export const ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA:TFormSchema<TRoomBookingFormKeys> = {
  GUESTS: { title: 'Guests', key: 'guests' },
  CHECK_IN: { title: 'Check In', key: 'check-in' },
  CHECK_OUT: { title: 'Check Out', key: 'check-out' },
  FIRST_NAME: { title: 'First Name', key: 'firstName' },
  LAST_NAME: { title: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName' },
  EMAIL: { title: 'Email', key: 'email' },
  MOBILE: { title: 'Mobile', key: 'mobileNo' },
  REQUEST: { title: 'Request', key: 'request' },
};

just do the following and it will have a proper type interface.
export const ROOM_BOOKING_FORM_SCHEMA = {
  GUESTS: { title: 'Guests', key: 'guests' },
  CHECK_IN: { title: 'Check In', key: 'check-in' },
  CHECK_OUT: { title: 'Check Out', key: 'check-out' },
  FIRST_NAME: { title: 'First Name', key: 'firstName' },
  LAST_NAME: { title: 'Last Name', key: 'lastName' },
  EMAIL: { title: 'Email', key: 'email' },
  MOBILE: { title: 'Mobile', key: 'mobileNo' },
  REQUEST: { title: 'Request', key: 'request' },
} as const;

and there you go you have the single source of truth with proper type interface.
PS: if there is any other better appraoches than this i'm all ears.
